# why when I write this simple code it shows "The method max1(int, int) is undefined for the type overloading"

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to write this simple code and it just won't work and it does an error near the `System.out.println(max1(1 , 2));` line and it says:

> The method max1(int, int) is undefined for the type overloading
>
> **Thanks for helping**

```
public class overloading {


public class max {


    public int max1(int a , int b) {

        if(a > b) {

            return a;

        }
        else {

            return b;

        }

    }//max - method


}//max - class


public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println(max1(1 , 2));



}//main



}//main class
```

Comment: Make `max1` static or `new max().max1(1, 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main method, you have to instantiate the max class to use the max1 method(note Java class convention is camel case, so you should change this to **M**ax).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    max myMax = new max();
    System.out.println(myMax.max1(1 , 2));



}//main
```

Answer (score 1):

`max` class is an inner class of `overloading` , so to access method `max1` of `max` , first you need to create instance of `overloading` and then using instance of `overloading`, you need to create instance of `max`.

Below code would work:

```
public class overloading {

    public class max {

        public int max1(int a, int b) {

            if (a > b) {

                return a;

            } else {

                return b;

            }

        }// max - method

    }// max - class

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        overloading overloading = new overloading();
        max maxObj = overloading.new max();
        System.out.println(maxObj.max1(1, 2));

    }// main
}
```